# SQL select for serial column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

Assume I have a data with columns :

aa1, aa2, aa3, aa4, aa5, aa6

and so on.

I 'm looking for a select query where I can just mention something like :

`select aa[1 to n] from table`...

Is there any way to do it directly ?

Thanks

Comment: Nope.  That is not how SQL works (although you could use dynamic SQL).  Presumably, these should be separate rows in some sort of junction table.

Comment: I reject the premise of the question. You wouldn't have a table of the type you describe because that is a spreadsheet, and a database table IS NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Strawberry I have a sample database of calls in a year, divided into months where I have columns like local_call_M1, local_call_M2, local_call_M3 and so on, and multiple other fields with a similar type of format. I cannot write each column name. any other solution? and yes it's a spreadsheet.

Comment: See GL's comment

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB there is a system settings in database `information_schema` where are defined all schemas, tables, columns, etc.

Using this you can list all details about the table and use it to compose the "dynamic" query as you need.

Example of table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `aa1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa2` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa3` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa4` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa5` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa6` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa7` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aa8` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;
```

The query to `information_schema` to list the tables:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'stackoverflow' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'aa%'
```

And the result:

```
aa1,aa2,aa3,aa4,aa5,aa6,aa7,aa8
```

So you can then built your query as needed.

**Edit:**
In [SQL documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348(v=sql.110).aspx) is said: "Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. **The only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to query the sys.objects catalog view**."